# LinearLayout two TextViews Side by Side not taking equal width

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have two side by side TextViews in LinearLayout, but second TextView taking more space than first one and i want both to take equal width that's why i have used `layout_weight="1"` but did not solve my issue, check below:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_margin="20dp"
     android:gravity="center">                                        

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                             
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/as_individual"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="As" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"                                      
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/for_company"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="For Company"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: layout_width must be 0dp

Comment: @Seinmon thanks solved my issue, post as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `layout_wight` for horizontal `Linearlayouts` `android:layout_width` must be `"0dp"` and for vertical layouts you need to set `android:layout_height="0dp"`

Answer (score 3):

try replace

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

by

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

for each TextView.

works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Change the attribute **android:layout_height** of the Textviews to

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

you were restriting width to "wrap_content" and that was the problem as the first textview's content was less than second's here is what you should do.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="This is first"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="This is second asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```